# Ugly: Set value of CheckBox from Boolean in python2.7/Tk

Tags: python, python-2.7, checkbox, tkinter, flags

I want to have a Boolean flag in my program, that can be set from the command line upon start and from the GUI while the program is running.

I use `OptParser` to parse the options from the command line and give it as a variable into the class representing the GUI. The problem seems to be that the CheckBox needs a `Tkinter.BooleanVar` to work correctly.

This is a minimal working example

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*

from __future__ import print_function
from Tkinter import *
from optparse import OptionParser

class CheckBox:

  def __init__(self, parent, verbose):
    self.verbose = BooleanVar()
    if verbose:
      self.verbose.set(True)
    else:
      self.verbose.set(False)
    myParent = parent
    menubar = Menu(myParent)
    myParent.config(menu=menubar)
    menubar.add_checkbutton(label="Toggle Verbose",
                                 variable=self.verbose,
                                 )
    menubar.add_command(label="Check Verbose", command=self.checkVerbose)

    checkVerbose = Button(text="Check Verbose", command=self.checkVerbose)
    checkVerbose.pack()

    chk = Checkbutton(text="Toggle Verbose",
                           variable=self.verbose,
                           onvalue=TRUE,
                           offvalue=FALSE,
                           )
    chk.pack()

  def checkVerbose(self):
    print(self.verbose.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
  parser = OptionParser(usage=usage, version="%prog v0.1.x")
  parser.add_option('-v', '--verbose',
                    action='store_true',
                    dest='verbose',
                    help='enables output to command line'
                    )
  parser.set_defaults(verbose=False)
  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

  # start the program
  root = Tk()
  CheckBox(root, options.verbose)
  root.mainloop()
  exit(0)
```

The code is working as it is here, but I got the feeling that I'm doing something wrong, as the part where I set `self.verbose` seems overly complex:

```
def __init__(self, parent, verbose):
  self.verbose = BooleanVar()
  if verbose:
    self.verbose.set(True)
  else:
    self.verbose.set(False)
```

…

In my opinion there should be something here that looks more like:

```
def __init__(self, parent, verbose):
  self.verbose = verbose
  …
```

The problem here is, that the two `CheckBoxes` correctly synchronize over the variable (of type `Tkinter.BooleanVar`), but every other access from my code seems to access another `self.verbose` variable which is a normal `Boolean`.

Is there any way to prettify this ugly construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just pass the boolean to the checkbox, because the boolean is immutable. You'd have to get the new value from the checkbox one way or another, and since you are also syncing two independent widgets, `BooleanVar` is the right way to go.

You can, however, replace the block

```
self.verbose = BooleanVar()
if verbose:
    self.verbose.set(True)
else:
    self.verbose.set(False)
```

with just the line

```
self.verbose = BooleanVar(value=verbose)
```

Comment: So my guess was correct )-: At least its now only one line…